# .net mvc partial for showing child elements that exist in different models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, models

I have an application that has products. Each product belongs to a brand and a category.

I have my models structured so when I get a category or brand, all the products within either are returned as an IEnumberable.

How do I create on partial view that I can use in either my main brand or category view that will display the products no matter what the current model is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a view which is strongly typed to List of `Product` and keep it under a shared location. (`~/Views/Shared` folder with a name `ProductList.cshtml`)

```
@IList<Product>
@{
   Layout=null;  //assuming this is for ajax (Popups).so no layout needed.
 }
@foeach(var prod in Model)
{
  <p>@prod.Name</p>
  <p>@prod.Price</p>
}
```

You can use this view to show list of Product, no matter it belongs to brand / category /whatever

```
public ActionResult ShowProductsForBrand(int brandId)
{
    List<product> products=GetProductsForBrand(brandId);
    return View("~/Views/Shared/ProductList.cshtml",products)
}

public ActionResult ShowProductsForCategory(int catId)
{
    List<product> products=GetProductsForCategory(catId);
    return View("~/Views/Shared/ProductList.cshtml",products)
}
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think this was what I was intending. Whenever I retrieve a brand or category model, I already have a list of the products as property of this model. How can make my partial views work with data I already have and not make another unnecessary call?

Comment: what you mean by another call ? if you have data in the model, you should simply pass it to the view. Am i misunderstanding your question ?

Comment: you're right, sorry about that. I was using `@Html.RenderAction()`
when I need to pass my data to `@Html.Partial()`